# Sharepoint 2013 Custom List Calculate difference between Today and Column Value

Tags: list, javascript, column

I'm attempting to use update a Column `[Days Since Last Contact]` by calculating the different between `=TODAY()` and a Column `[Date of Last Contact]`.

I've been trying to use `[Day Since Last Contact]` as a calculated column, but the list doesn't update this column unless the item has been edited.

The goal is to have the Days Since column update every time someone loads the page.  Any idea how to go about this?  I can't see to find a way to attach javascript to the list for this purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The other answer refers to (outdated) 2011 knowledge

See the 2015 posts:

- [Calculated formulas for tracking progress](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/162343/calculated-formulas-for-tracking-progress/162344#162344)
- [How to use Today and Me in Calculated column](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/151144/how-to-use-today-and-me-in-calculated-column/151336#151336)
- [Help with Dual Javascript countdown clock](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/158703/help-with-dual-javascript-countdown-clock/159853#159853)

Comment: I have used img onload in views at other places, never thought about calculated columns. Thanks!

Comment: Be aware of some minor drawbacks: http://www.viewmaster365.com/#/How

Answer (score 0):

Calculated fields are not updated until item itself is updated, please check this question:

[calculated field - formula for ageing](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/22536/calculated-field-formula-for-ageing)